# Trying to mess around with a sample extension but my JS doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm messing around with the Page Redder sample extension, however I can't figure out why my JS won't work. The original extension changes the background color to red when the extension is clicked. I'm trying to make it so it changes certain words found by their CSS selector to red instead, in my case the selector is "var.d" here is the JS: (The JS at the bottom that is commented in is the original code)

```
// Copyright (c) 2011 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can    be
// found in the LICENSE file.

// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
// No tabs or host permissions needed!
console.log('Turning ' + tab.url + ' red!');
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
code: 'document.querySelectorAll("var.d");'

for (var i = 0; i < xx.length; i++) {
xx[i].style.color="red";
}

 });
});


// 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red";
```

Comment: Can you please format your code a little better? Also it looks invalid to me, so double check you copied it over correctly and fix the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will not work because the for loop is not included in "code" attiribute and the xx variable is not declared.

Try the code below. Just make sure that "var.d" selectors really exist or else you will not get any result.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // No tabs or host permissions needed!
  console.log('Turning ' + tab.url + ' red!');
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'var xx = document.querySelectorAll("var.d"); for (var i = 0; i < xx.length; i++) {xx[i].style.color="red";}'});
  });
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. The website I'm testing this on is http://xahlee.info/js/js_get_elements.html and "var.d" does exist unless I'm reading something wrong. I also tried changing the selector to simply "a" to test it and it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Also, did you update the extension after saving the code? I tested that using "a" and it works on all site.

Comment: There is no html file because there is no popup, you simply click the extension and it should work. I'm not sure why your code isn't working for me, someone on reddit found a fix that worked which was replacing the ' ' with ` ` so it looks like this:     /*chrome.tabs.executeScript({
  code: `var xx = document.querySelectorAll("div#player-api.player-width.player-height.off-screen-target.player-api");
    for (var i = 0; i < xx.length; i++) {
    xx[i].style.position="fixed";
    }` //NOTICE you used ` instead of ' that makes the diff
  });*/ I can't really format it well because enter publish

Comment: es the comment. I appreciate the help though!